# UITableView scrolls to wrong position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and I inserted a lot of cells. Each cell contains a `UITextField`. I would like to scroll automatically to the focused `UITextField`. But if I remove a cell, `UITableView` can't scroll to the correct `UITextField`, the keyboard overlaps the focused `UITextField`

````
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
    cellArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:_cell0, _cell1, _cell2, _cell3, _cell4, _cell5, _cell6, _cell7, _cell8, _cell9, _cell10, _cell11, _cell12, _cell13, _cell14, _cell15, nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [cellArray count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return [cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == _input0) {
        [cellArray removeObject:_cell1];
        [_tableView reloadData];
    }
        activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = nil;

}

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height+100, 0.0);

    _tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [_tableView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
     UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    _tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}```
````

Comment: So the problem is caused by `[cellArray removeObject:_cell1]; [_tableView reloadData];` That is not how to remove a cell. And removing a cell while the user is in the middle of editing within it is somewhat crazy. If you did that to me I'd delete your app.

Comment: Ahh, yes I was crazy, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

// remove Row at index path
[m_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

// insert row at index path
[m_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[m_indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];